# ddd gets inactive when mouse is moved out of its window

Tags: unix, x11, ddd-debugger

My ddd window doesn't take any keyboard input when my mouse cursor is moved out of the window. Although ddd window is still active, but it doesn't take any inputs. I will have to move my mouse over its window to make it work again. Is there a way to configure it in a way that it takes the input no matter where the mouse pointer is, just like any other X window, xterm for example.

Comment: Could you clarify if your window manager is configured with click-to-focus or follow-focus, and in the later case, if it's a special flavor of follow-focus? Do you encounter your problem when you move the cursor to the background or only to another window (yes, technically the background *is* another window but some window managers make an exception)?

Comment: The window manager (KDE) is configured with click-to-focus. Yes I face the problem as soon as mouse moves outside the ddd window, nomatter it is moving to background or to another window.
- MS

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem; DDD behaved like focus-follows-mouse, when all other windows (and the setting in gnome) was click-to-focus. This was in DDD 3.3.11.
For me, it (mostly) works now, after I changed "Keyboard focus" to "Click to type" in the Preferences, Startup tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your are under unix, right? That depends on your window manager. The current behavior is called "focus follow mouse."

OTOH, the commenter is right to point out that if DDD is the only program showing this problem, it might be something else. One idea is to turn of some tool auto raise magic, as indicated in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/manual/ddd/html_mono/ddd.html#Customizing%20Tool%20Position).

Comment: I would have liked the question to be clearer, but while your answer is the same as comes naturally to me, I don't think that's it. The "just like any other X window, xterm for example" makes me think there's something special about `ddd` the OP is asking about.

Comment: Thats right I am on linux. But all the other windows on my system doesnt behave like this. I never want this feature "focus follow mouse", it happens only for my ddd window

Answer (score 0):

If `ddd` implements some sort of follow-focus itself instead of relying on the window manager, I am afraid that it's not going to be easy to prevent it. The good news is that `ddd` doesn't do anything very smart, it's just a front-end for real debuggers (say, `gdb`). So if you don't find any way to fix it, you can easily switch to any other front-end (say, [Emacs](http://www.linux-france.org/article/appli/emacs/manuel/html/debuggers.html)).